# Is there a way to make a bihistogram plot?

Tags: graphics, histograms

Is there a way of making a bihistogram plot in mathematica?

There is a reference to it at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bihistogram.html but no suggestions as to how to do it.

Comment: Are you looking for [PairedHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedHistogram.html)?

Answer (score 15):

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.3, 1], 1000];
```

One way is [`PairedHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedHistogram.html)

```
PairedHistogram[data1, data2]
```

[image]

A different layout can be achieved by hacking the height specification of [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html).

```
Show[
 Histogram[data1, Automatic],
 Histogram[data2, Automatic, -#2 &]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

In practice, we often deal with datasets of different sizes. Thus instead of the `"Count"` height specification, we may want `"PDF"` or something else.

Here I provide explicit functions for some of the usual height specifications.

```
count = #2;
pdf = -(#2/(Total[#2] Subtract @@@ #1)) &;
probability = #2/Total[#2] &;
intensity = -(#2/Subtract @@@ #1) &;
```

These correspond exactly to the specifications `"Count"`, `"PDF"`, `"Probability"` and `"Intensity"`, but they are expressed as a function, so we can easily put a minus sign in front to flip the bars.

Example with datasets of different sizes:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1.5], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.7], 10000];

bs = 0.2; (* manually fixed bin size *)
Show[
 Histogram[data1, {bs}, pdf (* or "PDF" *)],
 Histogram[data2, {bs}, -pdf[##] &],
 PlotRange -> 0.7 {-1, 1} (*manual plot range to center axis *)
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the `Histogram` hight specification solution!

Comment: And a simple trick to get different colours in the second example (while using Mathematica's default palette) would be `Show[Histogram[data1, Automatic], Histogram[{{}, data2}, Automatic, -#2 &]]`

Comment: I think this will work very nicely. Thanks very much. One small additional question for the rotated plot -- how can I ensure that the bin width, height and range are the same for both histograms?

Comment: The data I am plotting has one histogram that is higher and has a longer tail than the other one. I'd actually like the option of either centering the horizontal axis or adjusting it up or down.

Comment: @PeterBlunden Use a manual bin(-size) specification for both to ensure the same bin size (second argument).  You can use `PlotRange` in `Show` to set the vertical range (and thus set the visual location of the center axis which is at 0).

Comment: @PeterBlunden I updated the post.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I want. Thanks so much.